# Привязка DataGridViewComboBoxColumn к таблице БД

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

БД - MS SQL SERVER
Есть таблица  magnito_defectoscope в базе данных с структурой (id(int), name(varchar), number(varchar)) пытаюсь привязать эту таблицу к DataGridViewComboBoxColumn , что бы в выпадающем списке было содержимое столбца number.
В итоге у меня надпись есть на комбобоксах с номерами, а выпадающий список не открывается и не активен[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Другие два столбца заполняются из другой таблицы базы данных. Что может быть не так?

```
            DataSet ds = dBConnection.getSet("SELECT * FROM magnito_defectoscope;");
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn test = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            bindingSource1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            test.Name = "test";
            test.DataSource = bindingSource1; 
            test.ValueMember = "id";
            test.DataPropertyName = "id"; 
            test.DisplayMember = "number"; 
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(test);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Товарищи, ответ найден путем проб и ошибок, все дело в пресловутом DataGridView, а если быть точнее, то в свойстве dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true; Он не давал редактировать таблицу и соответственно не давал открыть комбобокс с выбором элементов!!!! 
И если прописать dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;, то все работает!
Так же, если будут замечания или рекомендации прошу оставить Коментарии.